# p:SelectOneMenu default value in edit mode

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using primefaces and have a datatable that has 2 columns. One column is outputtext another one is selectOneMenu. I made editable selectOneMenu. Actually it's work but not properly. Default value of selectItem is shown null but ı want it to show first value as default value. How can I make it?

```
    <p:dataTable id="cellEditingTable" var="message"
    value="#{messageTableController.menuList}" paginator="true"
    paginatorPosition="bottom" editable="true" editMode="cell">
        <p:column>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="menu" value="#{messageTableController.selected}"
                style="width:96%" effect="fold" editable="true">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{message.assign}"
                    itemValue="#{message.assign}" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{message.combo}"
                    itemValue="#{message.combo}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

I change selectOneMenu's value to first ItemValue. So when run the program,  first ItemValue picked selected item as a default.

```
    <p:selectOneMenu id="menu" value="#{message.assign}"
        style="width:97%" editable="true">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{message.assign}"
            itemValue="#{message.assign}" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{message.combo}"
            itemValue="#{message.combo}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add noSelectionOption to the first selectItem

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="#{message.assign}"
                    itemValue="#{message.assign}" noSelectionOption="true" />
```

Comment: When I use the noSelectionOptios="true" it returns just 's' as a first item of combobox.

Answer (score 1):

May be late to answer this.
If you use `editable="true"` then while rendering in the browse, it will render as textbox.

Remove the `editable="true"` then the default value will be selected.

If you want to provide the filter option in the selectOneMenu, use `filter="true"`

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="menu" value="#{message.assign}"
    style="width:97%" filter="true">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{message.assign}"
        itemValue="#{message.assign}" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{message.combo}"
        itemValue="#{message.combo}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Based on the editable property, it will render in browser as below.
[image: Render in Browser based on editable property]